# Remove special characters from text file in Windows

Tags: powershell

I want to output text from a text file in Windows script like you can in Linux with `grep`:

```sh
grep -ve ^# -ve '^;' -ve ^$ /name of file.
```

I haven't had much success finding a solution. I am trying to use Powershell with little experience using it.

Comment: P.S. I don't not want to modify the file, just remove special characters and anything commented so I don't have to look the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select-String` in place of `grep`:

```
Select-String -Path 'path/to/file' -Pattern '^[#;]|^$' -NotMatch
```

`Select-String` will output a `Match` object, if you just want to matched strings, grab the `Line` property:

```
Select-String ... |Select -Expand Line
```

Starting with PowerShell 7.0 you can also use the `-Raw` switch to have `Select-String` return only the matched strings and nothing else:

```
Select-String ... -Raw
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes close.  You can have an array of patterns seperated by commas.  Just like in bash, the semicolon has to be quoted, because it means "end of statement" in powershell.  The command avoids lines that start with "#", ";", or are blank.

```
'# comment',
'; semicolon',
'',
'one',
'two',
'three' | select-string ^#, '^;', ^$ -notmatch

one
two
three
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to output I was after; get-childitem zabbix_agentd.conf | select-string -pattern '^[#;]|^$' -notmatch

This is what I was after without all the lines that are commented out and spaces.
    zabbix_agentd.conf:24:LogFile=C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\zabbix_agentd.log
    zabbix_agentd.conf:88:Server=10.0.0.22
    zabbix_agentd.conf:130:ServerActive=10.0.0.22
    zabbix_agentd.conf:141:Hostname=RED-DOUG
    zabbix_agentd.conf:257:Include=C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent\zabbix_agentd.conf.d\

Thank you for the help, Doug